# Custom @ConfigurationProperties validator

Tags: java, spring, spring-validator

I'm trying to create a custom `Validator` for a `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated class.
The `@Validated` annotation has the `Class<?>[] value()` attribute, on which apparently is where you set the custom validator. I attempted the following with no luck:

```
public class SomePropertiesValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return SomeProperties.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        SomeProperties properties = (SomeProperties) target;
    }

}

@Validated(SomePropertiesValidator.class)
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some.prefix")
public class SomeProperties {

    // ...
 
}
```

None of the `SomePropertiesValidator` methods are triggered at all. The only way I got it to work, is implementing `Validator` within the `SomeProperties` class, but that's not what I'm looking for.

I also tried annotating `SomePropertiesValidator` with `@Component` and injecting it manually with the help of the `@Bean` annotation (also tried it within a static method).

Answer (score 1):

According to Spring's documentation, the custom validator `SomePropertiesValidator` needs to be created statically under the name of `configurationPropertiesValidator`. By doing so, we're creating a global `@ConfigurationProperties` validator.

"You can also add a custom Spring Validator by creating a bean definition called configurationPropertiesValidator. The @Bean method should be declared static. The configuration properties validator is created very early in the application’s lifecycle, and declaring the @Bean method as static lets the bean be created without having to instantiate the @Configuration class. Doing so avoids any problems that may be caused by early instantiation."

Example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SomeProperties.class)
public class SomeConfig {

    @Bean
    public static SomePropertiesValidator configurationPropertiesValidator() {
        return new SomePropertiesValidator();
    }

}
```

In case you need more than one custom validator, the only way to achieve this is by implementing the `Validator` interface on your `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated classes.

Reference: [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.validation)

Comment: Also you can use ConstructorBinding and implement needed logic, here is link to the Spring doc (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.constructor-binding).

Answer (score -1):

According to The source code doc.

```
    /**
     * Specify one or more validation groups to apply to the validation step
     * kicked off by this annotation.
     * <p>JSR-303 defines validation groups as custom annotations which an application declares
     * for the sole purpose of using them as type-safe group arguments, as implemented in
     * {@link org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter}.
     * <p>Other {@link org.springframework.validation.SmartValidator} implementations may
     * support class arguments in other ways as well.
     */
    Class<?>[] value() default {};
```

This parameter is used for validation group.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).